# Is this subspace L-embedded?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Consider the following subspace of $L^1(0,1)$. Let $Z$ be the subspace of all integrable functions that integrate to zero. So, $f \in Z$ implies
$$ \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = 0.$$

How to show that this space is not L-embedded (or is it L-embedded)?

It is known that $L^1(0,1)$ is L-embedded, but this property does not always pass to subspaces.

Comment: What means $L$-embedded?

Comment: An L-embedded Banach space is a Banach space which can be complemented
in its bidual, in which the norm is additive between the space and its complement. The best example is L^1. Its dual is L^\infty and the dual of L^\infty is the space of all additive measures. This space can be decomposed into its L^1 piece (countable additive measures) and the left over singular piece.